# Spark Stage performance, found GC Time very high just for few tasks

Tags: performance, apache-spark, garbage-collection, rdd

I'm trying to tune a Spark application, in order to reduce overall time execution, but I'm having a strange behaviour during a Stage execution.

Basically just 14/120 tasks needs around 20 min to finish, the others instead take 4 or 5 min to be completed.

Looking a the Spark UI, the partitioning seems good, the only difference I see is the GC Time that is very high for the 14 tasks.

I attach an image of the situation.

Do you have any idea for find the performance solution?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to show GC times for individual tasks. You should capture a GC log of one of the slow tasks and post it here.

Comment: Sorry, my fault,  I just attached another image showing GC Time

Comment: That doesn't show high GC times

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and could resolve it by using Parallel GC instead of G1GC. You may add the following options to the executors additional Java options in the submit request

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

Comment: -XX:+UseParallelOldGC automatically adds -XX:+UseParallelGC